# Need help understanding this line of code (dictionaries, keys, pandas, numpy)

Tags: python

I'm attempting a [Google Crash Course](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/first-steps-with-tensorflow/programming-exercises) to learn TensorFlow and Machine Learning.
I am having trouble comprehending one of the lines from their [coding examples](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/mlcc/first_steps_with_tensor_flow.ipynb?utm_source=mlcc&utm_campaign=colab-external&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=firststeps-colab&hl=en#scrollTo=ubhtW-NGU802).

```
def my_input_fn(features, targets, batch_size=1, shuffle=True, num_epochs=None):
"""Trains a linear regression model of one feature.

Args:
  features: pandas DataFrame of features
  targets: pandas DataFrame of targets
  batch_size: Size of batches to be passed to the model
  shuffle: True or False. Whether to shuffle the data.
  num_epochs: Number of epochs for which data should be repeated. None = repeat indefinitely
Returns:
  Tuple of (features, labels) for next data batch
"""

# Convert pandas data into a dict of np arrays.
features = {key:np.array(value) for key,value in dict(features).items()}
```

---

I need help understanding that last line of code.

```
features = {key:np.array(value) for key,value in dict(features).items()}
```

---

[I've researched dictionaries](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/how-to-use-dictionaries-in-python) in an attempt to understand it myself, but it's still a bit much for me to grasp. I've attempted to write the same line of code in a way I can understand:

```
np_dict_array = dict(features).items()

for key,value in np_dict_array:
    features += np_dict_array[key]
```

I do not think I am rewriting the code correctly. To get specific, I need help understanding what this does in that line of code:

```
key:np.array(value)
```

---

If anybody could explain what that line of code is doing, or (bonus points) rewrite it in a novice-friendly way, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a 'dictionary comprehension' - modelled on a list comprehension, but making a new dictionary instead.

```
features = {key:np.array(value) for key,value in dict(features).items()}
```

take things from the inside out:

```
dict(features)    # make a dictionary from the `features` argument
    .items()      # make a list of (key,value) tuples
for key,value     # iterate on those tuples
np.array(value)   # make a numpy array from the value
key:...           # make a new entry in the new dictionary
```

In sum, it makes a dictionary from `features`, making sure that the `value` for each item is a numpy array.

```
fdict = dict(features)
adict = dict()   # empty dictionary
for key,value in fdict.items():
    adict[key] = np.array(value)
```

Answer (score 2):

> features = {key:np.array(value) for key,value in dict(features).items()}

It is a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/). It converts all values in `dict(features)` to a Numpy array.

> key:np.array(value)

This is how you assign key value pairs to a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Alternate syntax:

```
features = {}
for key, value in dict(features).items():
    features[key] = np.array(value)
```

Comprehensions are popular as they reduce this sort of common pattern down to a single line. However, it is sometimes tempting to try to do too much in a comprehension as complexity grows.